# Applescript 'whose extension is' DWG/STEP

Tags: python, applescript, rhino3d

I need a script to read every .dwg/.step in a selected folder and its subfolders then proceed to a sequence of clicks to save the files on the same folder then close it.

Here is what I have, Applescripts doesn't recognize the .dwg/.step extension instruction.

```
set MyFolder to (choose folder)

tell application "Finder"
set MyFiles to every file of entire contents of MyFolder whose name extension is ("DWG" or "STEP")
return MyFiles -- this doesn't return anything

repeat with aFile in MyFiles
    tell application "Rhinoceros"
        open aFile
        activate
        delay 1
    end tell
    tell application "System Events" -- the instruction is given 'manually'
        click at {150, 1}
        delay 1
        click at {150, 180}
        delay 1
        click at {680, 335}
        delay 1
        click at {600, 495}
        delay 1
        click at {900, 510}
    end tell

    delay 1

end repeat
end tell
```

I'm a beginner with applescript but this application would save tons of hours of work!
Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: @CJK, It was a temporary issue with my system and is now fixed. FWIW I created some dummy.dwg and dummy.step files with `touch` and Finder would not return the name extension property because the extensions were not registered with launch services. Once registered Finder worked. System Events worked either way.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is the use of the `or` operator inside parenthesis which is being performed on two string values.  This doesn't make sense to AppleScript, nor should it.  The correct expression would be:

```
...whose name extension is "DWG" or name extension is "STEP"
```

although *Finder* does let you combine these predicates into a list upon which it can operate collectively:

```
...whose name extension is in {"DWG", "STEP"}
```

Also, move your final `end tell` to the just after declaring your `MyFiles` variable—there's no need (and it's actively obstructive) to enclose the *System Events* operations inside the *Finder* block.

Thus your *Finder* command should end up looking something like:

```
tell application "Finder" to set MyFiles to (every file of the entire contents of ¬
    (choose folder) whose name extension is in {"DWG", "STEP"}) as alias list
```

I've coerced it to an `alias list` at the end there because it'll speed up the processing time, for some inexplicable reason.

---

The last part of your script is something I can't provide too much insight into without knowing more about this application "Rhinoceros".  I did a quick Google, but couldn't find anything.

But if it's able to understand the `open` command, that implies it's scriptable and it probably has a `save` command that goes along with it.

**NEVER** try and accomplish things by clicking at coordinates—it'll break with the slightest pin drop.  If the program isn't scriptable, it'll probably throw an error with the `open` command, in which case your best bet is to script its application process and access the menu `save` command.

But I think you're going to have a tough time implementing this successfully, whichever way you go.

---

***HOWEVER***, if all you want is, as you stated, to save those files inside a single folder, then you needn't try and use *Rhinoceros* at all.  Instead, use *Finder* to `duplicate` (or `move`) the files to a new location:

```
tell app "Finder" to duplicate MyFiles to MyFolder
```

or

```
tell app "Finder" to move MyFiles to MyFolder
```

This can all be condensed into a single line, so your entire script (if this is what you indeed want the outcome to be) would simply become:

```
set myfolder to (choose folder)

tell application "Finder" to move (every file of the entire contents of myfolder ¬
    whose name extension is in {"DWG", "STEP"}) as alias list to myfolder
```

Comment: Indeed, Applescript doesn't recognize Rhinoceros at all (no librairy), it can open the app via finder but can't make it open a document, I always have an error message.

(-tell application "Finder"
-open application "Rhinoceros"
-end tell)
I need to open every document in Rhinoceros to export them to another format (didnt mention it before).

I am thinking of using a Python script to do that, as the applescript is not the best solution.

I still have a problem recognizing the DWG format.